Under unusual daylight, delicate leaves rustle lightly
5th September 1964, ??:??:?? (UTC), somewhere in Romania: Under unusual daylight, delicate leaves rustle lightly, revealing bright autumn skies - Bob's set is reversed. (B > b)
How does that sum to 44396175618?
Birthday Hint:

 [Unix Timestamp] + [11-digit number] + [7-digit number].I think it's best to focus on the first two, if you get them correct the last will reveal itself anyway.


Note: The mathematics is only here because it is recommended to use it with the calculation-puzzle tag. No deeper mathematical knowledge is required.

Where did you get that puzzle from?

@M.Riyan From the depths of my mind, and with the help of the internet to get everything correct and make it work.

Something related to Hitman-Agent 47?
